# Per row size limits in BigQuery data?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a limit to the amount of data that can be put in a single row in BigQuery? Is there a limit on the size of a single column entry (cell)? (in bytes)

Is there a limitation when importing from Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The largest size of a single row allowed is 1MB for CSV and 2 MB for JSON. There are no limits on field sizes, but obviously they must be under the row size as well.

These limits are described [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery).

Comment: This answer is out of date. The max row size is 100MB for CSV and JSON, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs